# Busca de strings em arquivo .log em Java

Tags: java

Preciso criar um programa em que eu consiga fazer uma busca em um arquivo .log e possa encontrar determinadas strings nele como por exemplo:

> O caminho de rede não foi encontrado.

Entre outras que representariam erros nesse arquivo de log, são elas que eu quero encontrar.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isto de forma simples?

Comment: Olá Matheus, o que você tentou, pode compartilhar seu código?

Comment: Qual o formato do LOG? Afinal não existe um formato padrão universal para todos logs.

Comment: É um arquivo de log do Robocopy do Windows, entendam como um arquivo .txt normal.
Tentei algumas coisas que achei pela internet, mas não salvei nenhuma pois achei melhor pegar uma idéia do zero e construir um código zerado, específico para o que eu preciso.

Comment: Mas o log foi criado por si ou por outro programa ?

Comment: O log é criado pelo Robocopy do Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter um `Stream<String>` que correpondem às linhas do arquivo usando [`File.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) (Java 8 ou superior).

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
File.lines(Paths.get("seu_arquivo.log"))
        .filter(x -> x.contains("O caminho de rede não foi encontrado."))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Se quiser colocar o número da linha junto:

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
File.lines(Paths.get("seu_arquivo.log"))
        .map(linha -> a.incrementAndGet() + "|" + linha)
        .filter(x -> x.contains("O caminho de rede não foi encontrado."))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Isso presume que o seu encoding seja UTF-8. Se for ISO-8859-1 ou algum outro, use o [método `lines` sobrecarregado que também recebe um `Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)):

```
File.lines(Paths.get("seu_arquivo.log"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

Comment: Porque o `AtomicInteger` ? o `lines` e/ou `map` é paralelizado em `Threads` diferentes ?

Comment: @Isac Não, não é paralelizado. Na verdade é porque se eu usasse uma variável do tipo `int`, o compilador reclamaria porque não posso alterar o valor de variáveis que não sejam *effectively final* dentro de lambdas. Uma alternativa seria usar um `int[1]`, mas isso é uma gambiarra muito feia que não gosto de ensinar os outros a fazer. Uma instância de uma classe local mutável só para isso é meio que um *overkill* e é uma outra gambiarra. Já o `AtomicInteger` é a solução que considero ser a mais limpa.

Comment: Certo, não me lembrei desse pormenor. Quando são tipos referências regra geral levam o `final` que nesse caso não serve.

Answer (score 0):

Por enquanto o código que consegui criar está ficando assim, o resultado mostra 3 valores com "O caminho da rede não foi encontrado" contidos neste log de exemplo, mas este foi só para aprender, como eu faria para adicionar mais ocorrências a este programa? Tenho pelo menos 5 ou mais códigos diferentes que gostaria que ele exibisse também, a idéia principal é atrelar a ocorrência dessas mensagens de erro, ao disparo de um sendmail, indicando que ocorreu algum problema em determinado backup e merece atenção extra.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String fileName = "C:\\users\\Matheus\\desktop\\backup_outlook.log";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {

                list = stream
                        .filter(line -> line.startsWith("O caminho da rede"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```